# Make content of ScrollView scroll behind a LinearLayout with a transparent background

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, footer, transparent

I have a vertical ScrollView with some ImageViews that I can scroll up and down. At the bottom of my application I have a footer consisting of a LinearLayout with a partly transparent background image (png). How do I achieve the following behavior?

[image]

Consider the following layout

```
<LinearLayout blah blah... >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/guesses_scroll_view_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/guesses_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bgrepeat"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/guesses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bgrepeat"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/peg_picker_bgrepeat"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        < some footer content />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```

What I got at the moment is something that looks like this

[image]

Since my background image peg_picker_bgrepeat is not rectangular, I get an ugly border above the ScrollView. How can I make the contents "scroll behind" the footer?

Comment: Added the images for you.

Comment: By writing `android:layout_above="@+id/footer"` you're telling the `ScrollView` to stay above the footer. It seems to me you should just get rid of that line to make the `ScrollView` and black/red pattern extend to behind the blue 'wave'. Do note this will create some overdraw - ideally you should optimize the images to minimize that (e.g. split the blue area in a 9-patch and 'wave' part and potentially make the stripe pattern a 9-patch too).

Comment: Scrollview with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and without android:layout_above="@+id/footer"

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove the line android:layout_above="@+id/footer" unless I want to screw up my layout. I'm quite new to android development, so I suppose my "coding style" is a bit fragile. However, I added android:layout_alignParentBottom to my scrollview which made the scrollview content go all the way down to the bottom of the screen. To avoid the contents at the bottom of the scrollview to be hidden behind the footer, I added a "dummy" (linear layout) at the bottom of the scrollview with the same height as the footer. This made the trick.